How add a new material ui autocomplete textinput from a dialog?
I use an Autocomplete component in a react js app to add and delete categories. To add a category I use a dialog.
When I press OK button in dialog box I manage to add the category in database and the category name appear in the inputtext of Autocomplete component of material ui. But when I press tab to move to the next text input in form, the text from textinput of Autocomplete component dissapear. Can you sugget me a solution that categorry name to persist in textinput of Autocomplete component when I press tab?
function EnterForm() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    amount: "",
    category: "",
    comment: "",
    date: "",
  });

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  const [newCategoryName, setNewCategoryName] = useState("");
  const [autocompleteInput, setAutocompleteInput] = useState(""); // Separate state for Autocomplete input
  const [alertOpen, setAlertOpen] = useState(false);
  


  const getTransactions = async () => {
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/read")
      .then((res) => setCategories(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const getCategory = async () => {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/readCategory")
      .then((res) => setCategories(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTransactions();
    getCategory();
  }, []);



  useEffect(() => {
    if (categories.length > 0) {
      const lastCategory = categories[categories.length - 1];
      setAutocompleteInput(lastCategory.autocomplete);
      setInput((prevInput) => ({
        ...prevInput,
        category: lastCategory.autocomplete,
      }));
    }
  }, [categories]);


  const handleOpenDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(true);
    setNewCategoryName(autocompleteInput); // Set the Dialog input to the Autocomplete input value
  };

  const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(false);

  };


  const handleAddCategory = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const categoryToAdd = { autocomplete: newCategoryName };
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/newcategory", categoryToAdd);
      const newCategory = response.data;
      setCategories((prevCategories) => [...prevCategories, newCategory]);
      
      setNewCategoryName("");
      setAutocompleteInput(newCategory.autocomplete); // Clear the Autocomplete input
      handleCloseDialog();
      setAutocompleteInput(newCategoryName.value);
      await getCategory();

  
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };


  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setAlertOpen(false);
  };


  return (
    <Grid container sx={{ margin: "5%" }} spacing={2} alignItems="center">
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
          Introdu tranzactie:
        </Typography>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <div style={{ width: "50%", margin: 5, textAlign: "left" }}>
          <Autocomplete
            fullWidth
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.autocomplete}
            options={categories}
            inputValue={autocompleteInput}
            onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => setAutocompleteInput(newInputValue)}
            onChange={(event, value) => setInput({ ...input, category: value ? value.autocomplete : "" })}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
            noOptionsText={
              <Button onClick={handleOpenDialog}>
                Add new category
              </Button>
            }
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Categorie" />}
            // onKeyDown={(event) => handleKeyDown(event, event.target.value)}
            renderOption={(props, option) => (
              <Box component="li" {...props} key={option._id}>
                {option.autocomplete}
                <IconButton
                  style={{ color: "#c70000" }}
                  sx={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
                  aria-label="delete"
                  onClick={(event) => {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    handleDeleteCategory(option._id);
                  }}
                >
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            )}


          />
        </div>
      </Grid>




      <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleCloseDialog}>
        <DialogTitle>Add a New Category</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To add a new category, please enter the category name here.
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="Category Name"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            variant="standard"
            value={newCategoryName}
            onChange={(e) => setNewCategoryName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleCloseDialog}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleAddCategory}>Add</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>





    </Grid>
  );
}

export default EnterForm;


Could you include a code example of your autcomplete and dialog component?

try and add disableClearable to the autocomplete component maybe this will help
